# Creating binary RGB values from image in python results in wrong size

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to extract binary values for red, green and blue from an image in python using OpenCV. The image has the size 224x224. I separate the values like this:

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
```

But when I print out the size of one color value with `print(sys.getsizeof(r))`, I get a result of 50288, even if 224x244 should be 50176.

There must be some overhead, does anyone know how I get values for the 50176 pixels?

I want to store the image values with classifier as binary file like this:
1 byte classifier + 50176 red values + 50176 green values + 50176 blue values

Comment: I don't know the python interface of OpenCV, but a Mat has definitely a header causing some overhead. Try `print(sys.getsizeof(r.data))`, although I am not sure `data` is the correct name for the field where the actual pixels are stored.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I didn't find documentation about `data` and using `r.data` printed out `64` but while searching further, I found another solution I'll provide in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')` returns a [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), which is in general the object type used by opencv to store images. Numpy array introduces indeed some overhead which causes the size of the object to be bigger than just the array buffer.

To check the size of the buffer, you can call for example [`img.nbytes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#array-attributes).

Comment: You are right, also splitting the images with `b,g,r = cv2.split(img)`  returns numpy arrays  those size is correctly printed as 50176 with `print(b.nbytes)`